# find pixels of given value in rank 3 tensor (e.g rgb image)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, boolean, mask

I wanted to use numpy to find the  array elements of a given value e.g.
 [2,3,4] (eg. these could be pixel vals). Should be simple but its thrown me for long enough that I turn to you o oracle.

I tried np.where and boolean but am comfustulated by the results :

```
In [4]: x=np.array([[[2,3,4],[4,5,6]],[[5,6,7],[6,7,8]]])

In [5]: x.shape
Out[5]: (2, 2, 3)

In [6]: np.where(x==[2,3,4])
Out[6]: (array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 1, 2]))

In [7]: [x==[2,3,4]]
Out[7]: 
[array([[[ True,  True,  True],
         [False, False, False]],

        [[False, False, False],
         [False, False, False]]], dtype=bool)]
```

i know i can do this

```
In [14]: import cv2

In [15]: cv2.inRange(x,np.array([2,3,4]),np.array([2,3,4]))
Out[15]: 
array([[255,   0],
       [  0,   0]], dtype=uint8)
```

but i was kind of wanting to avoid  using a cv2 cannon for a numpy mosquito

Comment: `(x==[2,3,4]).all(-1)` or `np.where((x==[2,3,4]).all(-1))`?

Comment: the first works, tho second doesnt and i  am not sure what numpy is returning here  , even in np.where(x==[2,3,4]), what is that answer?

Comment: The second one returns the row, col indices for the matches along the height and width of the image respectively. You didn't specify the expected output there in the question. Is the one from `cv2` the expected one?

Comment: yes i was after a boolean array of one less dimension ,  usable as mask .  how does the second one work  - what is the (array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 1, 2]))  answer to  np.where(x==[2,3,4])    ?

Comment: also what is all(-1) doing - i can't seem to find any docs on it

Comment: `np.where` gives us the indices of matches along each axis. So, for `np.where(x==[2,3,4])`, it gives indices along all three axes. `all(-1)` is basically `.all(axis=-1)` i.e. ALL reduction along last axis.